# Evaluating algebra found in other cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to calculate a value in column B, based on the formula present in column A. Ex: A1 would have the formula `"2 * 3"`, and B1 would have the formula something like: `"=(A1)"`. This should show the full formula in A1, and "6" as the result in B1. However, when I try this B1 is not able to correctly calculate. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you're wanting.  If cell A1 is `=2*3` then Excel will show you `6` for the cell.  In B1, are you wanting a way to show what formula is being used in A1? So the cell B1 shows `2*3`?

Comment: thank you so much for your kind reply Mr.Brucewayne, My need is calculate value of A1 i.e 2 * 3, is displayed in B1 as 6.

Comment: Ah okay, I've edited my answer. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Cell A1 has `2*3`, you can use this function to get `6`:

```
Public Function evaluate_Math(ByVal cellRef As Range)
evaluate_Math = Evaluate("=" & cellRef)
End Function
```

Put that in your worksheet module, and use `=evaluate_Math(A1)`

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Bruce It Works like a charm.Its Perfect.

Comment: Yay!  Do you mind marking as the answer then (click the white outline of a check mark left of the post), so other folks will see it was answered?